# Reading JSON file as a map using spring boot mechanisms

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to ask the spring boot gurus out there, how can I read a json file the Spring way and autowire it to a Map<String, Object> on my java controller.

I have come across this article where the author explains how to do this for a normal pojo with primitive types:
https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

I would like to know whats the best way to load this json the spring way and wire it to a Map<String, Object> field

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing JSON as input to your controller as input to your api and

1. If your JSON structure has a fixed structure create a class for it and use it as a Request body in your controller

Ex:

```
@GetMapping(/yourURL)
public @Responsebody YourResponseClass controllerFunction(@Requestbody 
ClassForJson request){

}
```

Spring will automatically map JSON to your class

2. If its Dynamic you can use String as request body and conver it to map using Gson Library

Gson is a library which maps your JSON string to a class, you can use Map class if you want to convert it to a Map

```
@GetMapping(/yourURL)
public @Responsebody YourResponseClass controllerFunction(@Requestbody String 
request){

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   Map map = gson.fromJson(request, Map.class);

}
```

1st method can be rewritten in the 2nd way as follows

```
@GetMapping(/yourURL)
public @Responsebody YourResponseClass controllerFunction(@Requestbody String 
request){

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map map = gson.fromJson(request, ClassForJson.class);

}
```

[For more information about Gson library, you can refer to this link](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map)